# "npm run dev" Command Doesn't Work - Giving "missing script: dev" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, svelte

I was trying to run this SVELT GitHub repo on local server:

https://github.com/fusioncharts/svelte-fusioncharts

I tried to launch it with "npm run dev" command. But I am seeing this error:

`npm ERR! missing script: dev`

I have tried to fix the issue by setting 'ignore-scripts' to false with this command:

`npm config set ignore-scripts false`

But it doesn't work.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Did you run `npm i` after you cloned it, like they state in the docs?

Comment: The `package.json` does not have a script named `dev`

Comment: If you look on repo package.json under scripts, you can see that script name is "prepublishOnly" and its property are npm run dev, you can do npm prepublishOnly

Comment: There is no `dev` script in the `package.json`. At this point you should open an issue to ping maintainers to clarify the README.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes.

Comment: @johannchopin OK

Comment: @dev Yes, I noticed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm ERR! missing script: dev` means you are there isn't a script having `dev`. You are likely running on an incorrect directory.

Fusion charts seem to work with svelte [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-fusion-charts-demo-1uoh4).

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have to go inside "examples" folder. I fixed the issue even before getting your answer. Nonetheless, thank you very much for taking your time looking at my   issue.

Answer (score 1):

`npm ERR! missing script: dev` means it cannot find a script called `dev` inside `package.json`.

That makes sense!

It looks at the [`package.json` inside the svelte-fusioncharts repo](https://github.com/fusioncharts/svelte-fusioncharts/blob/develop/package.json). In that file, there is a [`scripts` property](https://github.com/fusioncharts/svelte-fusioncharts/blob/develop/package.json#L6-L9).

Notice how that property looks as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "rollup -c",
  "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
}
```

It does not contain a `dev` script. That’s why it says there’s a missing script. Other commands will work, like `npm run build` or `npm run prepublishOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

Md. Ehsanul Haque Kanan,

```
  "scripts": {
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base public" }
```

The above is the script from the examples folder in the repo: https://github.com/fusioncharts/svelte-fusioncharts/blob/develop/examples/package.json

You have missed out on the "dev" script in your package.json file.

Please check the "package.json" file in your project and just add the "dev" script as in the repo link and then retry.

Comment: I’ve added an answer below. If that doesn’t help, someone else ran into a similar problem on the GitHub repository: https://github.com/fusioncharts/svelte-fusioncharts/issues/11 — If you’re still stuck getting in touch with them via GitHub may help

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I have fixed the issue. I just go inside examples folder. Then I run the following commands:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It is due to changes in script object in package.json by me. I had installed nodemon and to run the code, I changed the script lifecycle events `start` and `dev` in package.json to run the code via nodemon.
But even after installing nodemon, it was not reflecting in `devDependencies`, so I made manual entry in `package.json` with its version seeing from `package-lock.json`.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon":"^2.0.15"
  }
```

Making this arrangement, my code started as expected.
So, check your recent npm package installation and verify its reflection in `devDependencies` or `dependencies` in package.json.